# Questions list and favorite tags

Tags: support

Previously, when I hit "Questions", most of the questions shown was related to one my my favorite tags, with perhaps 2 or 3 non-favorite (white) questions per page of 15 question. Now, it's the other way around, most questions are white, sprinkled with 2-3 questions from my favorites. Which in turn means that most of the questions listed are about things I know nothing about.

Has there been some change here, some setting that I need to add or something?

Comment: I noticed this too - and it's well annoying!!

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer myself since I figured it out:

Pressing the stackoverflow-icon yields the old questions list, with a majority of faorites.

Comment: Many thanks! Didn't read anything about this before, and might had never found this.